# Add the same navigation bar and footer to multiple HTML views

Tags: html, css, footer, navigationbar

I've been asked to develop some simple views for an e-commerce website, but I can not use any framework, just raw HTML and CSS. My problem is that I do not want to repeat the navigation bar and footer code in each view. I am used to developing with Ruby on Rails, where I can solve this issue using partials.

Is there anything similar for this case or do I have to include the same code in each view (just because HTML is a static language)?

Thanks in advanced

Comment: Well if you can ONLY use HTML and CSS... then yes, you have to include the same code in each HTML file.

Answer (score 0):

This is where it can be useful to have a build script like [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/). Generally the process for things like static web pages is using a templating language like [Jade](http://jade-lang.com/) or [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/). With Jade, you could just write something like this:

```
html
   body
      include ./includes/header.jade
```

Then compile it using gulp

```
var jade = require('gulp-jade');

gulp.task('templates', function() {
  var YOUR_LOCALS = {};

  gulp.src('./lib/*.jade')
    .pipe(jade({
      locals: YOUR_LOCALS
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'))
});
```

Other than a build step, however, there is no way to repeat static content using pure HTML and CSS.

Comment: So you are using JS too lol?! you are a clown!

Comment: A build script is different from client side JS..

Comment: You may want to look into JavaScript build tools - they're pretty amazing and in wide use http://www.sitepoint.com/introduction-gulp-js/

Comment: Still the same thing, just built for you.

Comment: Go ahead and argue that gulp.js is not javascript, just makes you sound ignorant.

Comment: I'm not arguing that. OP's specifications are that the *website itself* can only include HTML and CSS, but using JS to compile HTML and CSS is possible. What do you think [jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/) is?

Comment: Do you need a compilation tool? Is there not an inline JS version of php `include`?

Answer (score -1):

You can create a separate footer and header html file then include them on your pages using php include like this `<?php include 'header.html';?>` and `<?php include 'footer.html';?>`

Just and them inline your main.html page wherever you want to add them.

or you can use Jquery like this:

```
<html> 
  <head> 
    <script src="jquery.js"></script> 
    <script> 
    $(function(){
      $("#includedContent").load("footer.html"); 
    });
    </script> 
  </head> 

  <body> 
     <div id="includedContent"></div>
  </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: OP says they only have access to HTML and CSS.

Comment: So then what would be wrong with the Jquery approach?

Comment: OP says they only have access to HTML and CSS. Not JS.

Comment: That means that there is no HTML or CSS function that allows code modularization?

Comment: Yeah, J4G's approach is still using JS so I don's know why he is having issues with it.